# xpath to match the specfic element based on inner html child tag text

Tags: python, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have an html as shown below

```
<div class="xtree">
       <img class="dojoimg">
       <span class="presentation">+</span>
 <span class ="treenode">
  <div class="ctreefolder">.... </div>
    <div class="presentationfolder">.... </div>
  <span >Setting</span>
 </span>
</div>
<div class="xtree">
       <img class="dojoimg">
       <span class="presentation">+</span>
 <span class ="treenode">
  <div class="ctreefolder">.... </div>
    <div class="presentationfolder">.... </div>
  <span >Home</span>
</span>
</div>
<div class="xtree">
       <img class="dojoimg">
       <span class="presentation">+</span>
 <span class ="treenode">
  <div class="ctreefolder">.... </div>
    <div class="presentationfolder">.... </div>
  <span >products</span>
</span>

</div>
```

I want to click the img icon based on the text in the last span tag.

for example , I want to select the first img tag , if the last span contains "Setting" . Can you please help me in writing xpath for this UI element to use in selenium webdriver python

Comment: Try this xpath : `//span[contains(text(), "Setting")]`

Comment: this //span[contains(text(), "Setting")] will click or find the element Setting. But I want to perform click on img tag(icon)

Comment: it will find it then use click()

Comment: nope I have tried it . It performs click on Setting . But I want it to click on img icon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this XPath will help you.Here i find the img class then match the text contains

```
//*[@class="dojoimg"]//span[contains(text(), "Setting")]
```

> Hope this concept will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution :

Using **find_element_by_link_text**

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text("Reveal").click()
```